# Repeating sequences in F#

Tags: f#

I have a 'compressed' stream of value to which is attached the number of occurence of that value, for instance :

```
let a = [ (),1; (),4; (),3;]
```

I would like to 'uncompress' that sequence and emit the original sequence.
I could define a repeat combinator to yield! to that effect

```
let rec repeat avalue n =  seq { if n > 0 then 
                                    yield avalue; yield! repeat avalue (n-1) }

let b = seq { for v,n in a do
                yield! repeat v n }  |> Seq.toList
```

Is there a way to express that inline, in the form of a composition ?

```
let c = a |> Seq.XXX(fun e -> ...)
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do this using `Enumerable.Repeat`:

```
> Seq.collect Enumerable.Repeat [ 1, 2; 3, 4; 5, 6 ] |> List.ofSeq;;
val it : int list = [1; 1; 3; 3; 3; 3; 5; 5; 5; 5; 5; 5]
```

Comment: ah, I did not know that one !

Comment: So this one is the best for tuples, which is the context of my question. Hence this is the most functional answer.

Comment: There's now also [`List.replicate<'T>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee353665.aspx).

Answer (score 3):

How about

```
let c = a |> Seq.collect (fun (v,i) -> [1..i] |> Seq.map (fun x -> v))
```

<s>I don't know a library function similar to Enumerable.Repeat; if someone knows of one, please add a comment.</s>

**EDIT**

I have found a library function similar to Enumerable.Repeat, though it is in the `List` module:

```
let c = a |> Seq.collect (fun (v,i) -> List.replicate i v)
```

This would be more elegant if the pairs in the source sequence were reversed:

```
let c = a |> Seq.collect ((<||) List.replicate)
```

So it seems that Enumerable.Repeat (as in the accepted answer) does indeed make the best solution, since its tupled argument matches the sequence elements:

```
let c = a |> Seq.collect Enumerable.Repeat
```

If anyone knows of a similarly elegant solution that stays within the F# library, please add a comment; thanks.

Comment: Nice, I didn't know there was an F# function (`<||`) similar to Haskell's `uncurry`!

Answer (score 3):

```
let rec repeat (item,n) = seq { if n > 0 then yield item; yield! repeat(item, n-1)}
a |> Seq.collect repeat
```

For example,

```
[('a',2); ('b',2)] |> Seq.collect repeat

val it: seq<char> = seq ['a';'a';'b';'b']
```

Comment: nice one. although it is  |> Seq.collect (fun (item,n) -> repeat item n)

Comment: My version with tupled `repeat` argument allows to get rid of lambda in the combinator.